# microsoft.containerregistry/registries' could not be found in subscription

Tags: azure, azure-acr

I am geeting the error while I try to attach the Azure Container Registry to the AKS using Visual studio
syntax:
`az aks update --name $CLUSTER_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --attach-acr $ACR_NAME`

Error:
microsoft.containerregistry/registries' could not be found in subscription

I have logged into the correct subscription and also set the correct subscription

```
az login --tenant $TENANT_ID
az account set --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION
```

az acr list also shows me the acr that is created

any possible solution for this?

Comment: Please check this it may help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760167/az-acr-unable-to-find-repository-in-case-of-multiple-subscription-on-single-ac

Answer (score 0):

Tested in my environment it is working fine for me, The error you are getting is due to you are looking into wrong subscription. When you use the CLI command `az login` then you log in with a `default` subscription. For you, it seems the "**Some Other susbscription**" is the default. You should check if your registry is in the current subscription. If not, you should set that subscription as the current subscription through the CLI command:

```
az account set --subscription subscription_id
```

Now would suggest you to check if the registry exists in current subscription with the CLI command:

```
az acr show -n acr_name
```

Also, you can set the subscription in the login time with the parameter `--subscription` through the CLI command `az login`.

***Reference : [az acr - Unable to find repository in case of multiple subscription on single account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760167/az-acr-unable-to-find-repository-in-case-of-multiple-subscription-on-single-ac)***