# The resource with name 'name' and type 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries' could not be found in subscription

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry, azure-container-service, acr

I am working on a script where I want to run `az acr import`. The command tries to list the repository but fails with the error: The resource with name 'name' and type 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries' could not be found in subscription

As you can see in the screenshot below. This registry is indeed present in the subscription. I am able to ***login, run docker push*** as well which completes successfully. But az acr show returns a failure.

[image]

Comment: Is the container registry part of the same subscription in the error code? Looks like while you're using az login > you are not logged into the subscription that has your container registry deployed. Try az account set --subscription subscription_id and then try az account set --subscription subscription_id  Reference :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760167/az-acr-unable-to-find-repository-in-case-of-multiple-subscription-on-single-ac

Comment: Yes it is part of same subscription. I azure az acr login to see if that helps somehow. But that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to log in to another Azure subscription and tried running

```
az acr show -n <acr-name>
```

and received same error code as yours even when the az acr log in command was successfull, refer below:-

[image]

When I ran the same commands and logged into the correct subscription where my ACR is deployed, Then I was able to retrieve acr details with `az acr show -n <acr-name>` command, Refer below:-

I am using sudo before every Azure CLI command to make sure I am running the scripts as a root user.

**Scripts:-**

Logged into my Azure account:-

```bash
sudo az login
```

Checked if the account is set to the correct subscription as my ACR:-

```bash
sudo az account set --subscription <subscription-id>
```

Logged into ACR:-

```bash
sudo az acr login --name <acr-name> --username siliconacr --password <password>
```

Ran the command:-

```bash
sudo az acr show --name siliconacr
```

Make sure you only add Container registry name and not the log in server name in the az acr show - n  command.

Output:-

[image]

[image]

If the issue persists try `az logout` command let and try logging in again as your Azure CLI in the ubuntu VM might have cached the credentials.

**Reference:-**

[azure - az acr - Unable to find repository in case of multiple subscription on single account - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760167/az-acr-unable-to-find-repository-in-case-of-multiple-subscription-on-single-ac)

Comment: I tried all this already which didn't help. I eventully uninstalled my az cli and cleared all the azure folders. But it still didn't help. Suprisingly I can see all the container registries using cloud shell or any other machine.

Comment: Are the container registries visible now? Or are they visible in another machines and not the current one?

Comment: Did you install az cli by this method and not curl in your linux machine - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt#option-2-step-by-step-installation-instructions

Comment: Also, Try az account clear command to clear azure cli's local cache and then try to log in again with correct subscription id. Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-clear and az logout is used to clear current subscription.

Comment: Refer - https://i.imgur.com/E7uPwO6.png

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the same error adding the resource group to the command.

```
az acr show -n <registryName> --resource-group <registry-resource-group>
```